# Oracle 11g: selecting all rows within 2 values

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I got 2 tables:

**Table L**

```
FROM | TO  | A     | B  
-----+-----+-------+-------
1    | 10  | bla1  | more1
11   | 20  | bla2  | more2
..   | ..  | ..    | ..
```

FROM - TO delimiting a range of values (here 1-10, 11-20, etc.)

**Table S**

```
VAL  | X     | Y
-----+-------+------
1    | foo1  | bar1
2    | foo2  | bar2
..   | ..    | ..
15   | foo15 | bar15
..   | ..    | ..
```

Etc.

I'm want to populate a table `R` from these two tables as follow:

**Table R**

```
VAL  | X    | Y     | A     | B  
-----+------+-------+-------+-----
1    | foo1 | bar1  | bla1  | more1
2    | foo2 | bar2  | bla1  | more1
..   | ..   | ..
15   | foo15| bar15 | bla2  | more2
..   | ..   | ..
```

**Business Logic**

For each row of S, insert `S.VAL`, `S.X` and `S.Y` into R, along with the `L.A` and `L.B` corresponding values.
The corresponding values being defined by having `L.FROM <= S.VAL <= L.TO`.

**Question**

Could someone suggest a direction to achieve that in either SQL (ideally) or PL/SQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've pretty much got the answer in your explanation, at least assuming the range don't overlap; join the two table with the logic `L.FROM <= S.VAL <= L.TO`, which as a join condition becomes

```
L.FROM <= S.VAL AND S.VAL <= L.TO
```

So you you can have an `insert ... select ...` using a query with that join condition:

```
insert into r (val, x, y, a, b)
select s.val, s.x, s.y, l.a, l.b
from s
join l on l."FROM" <= s.val and s.val <= l."TO"
```

Hopefully your columns aren't really called 'from' and 'to', but I've used quoted identifiers in case they are.

Alternatively you could make `R` a view using that query, instead of a table you need to maintain separately with redundant data.

---

You could use `between` instead, as:

```
join l on s.val between l."FROM" and l."TO"
```

but that's translated under the hood to

```
join l on s.val >= l."FROM" and s.val <= l."TO"
```

which is the same logic, and I prefer the expanded form as it's clearer and more explicitly inclusive.

Comment: Thanks. Great answer (and suggesting the view). Marked as correct and up voted!

Comment: Is there a way to use alias for S and L ?

Comment: @HeyStackExchange - not sure what you mean. You can do `select s.val ... from long_name l join some_other_name s on s.val ...`. That is just normal table aliasing though...

Comment: Thanks, that's the alias I was looking for